# Converting each character to a list element?

Tags: python

I have a sentence such as this:

```
sentence = "My name's Bob."
```

and I would like to get it like this:

```
list = ["M", "y", " ", "n", "a", "m", "e", "'", "s", " ", "B", "o", "b", "."]
```

I need the spaces and all punctuations to be in the list. How would one go about doing this? Thank you.

Comment: `list(sentence)`

Comment: Another way: [ x for x in sentence ]

Answer (score 1):

Since strings in python are iterable, you can simply call the [built-in list()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) to transform your string for you.

```
list(sentence)
```

I would like to note, you should not name it `list`.
If you do this, it will overwrite the function.

```
>>> sentence = "My name's Bob."
>>> sentence_as_list = list(sentence)
>>> print(sentence_as_list)
['M', 'y', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', "'", 's', ' ', 'B', 'o', 'b', '.']
```

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't know it was so simple. Thank you and I'll change the name of the list.